# Changing the tabs manually in jquerytools to have a default tab when mouse is out of the tab container

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-tools

I have a perfect working jquerytools accordion / tabs that change with mouse hover.

I want that when the mouse is out of the tabs container, a default tab to be activated instead the last activated tab.

My javascript is as follows:

```
$(function() {
    $("#accordion").tabs("#accordion div", {
    tabs: 'img.tab',
    effect: 'fade',
    event: 'mouseover'
    });     
});

$('#accordion').mouseout(function(){
    // How should I activate a special tab?
});
```

---

**EDIT**

The HTML of `#accordion` container:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <!-- accordion header #1 -->
    <div>
        <img src="img/sample-tab-content.png" />
    </div>
    <img class="tab" src="./img/tab-title-activities.png" />

    <div>
        <h3>apprenticeship</h3>
        <p>Cras diam. Donec dolor lacus, vestibulum at, varius in, mollis id, dolor. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
    <img class="tab" src="./img/tab-title-apprenticeship.png" />

    <div>
        <h3>association</h3>
        <p>Non lectus lacinia egestas. Nulla hendrerit, felis quis elementum viverra, purus felis egestas magna.</p>
    </div>
    <img class="tab" src="./img/tab-title-association.png" />
</div>
```

Images with `class="tab"` are the tabs and their above HTML are tab contents.

I can now see that I have even problem with detecting the `mouseout` event of `#accordion` container.

Even the following code doesn't work:

```
$('#accordion').mouseout(function(){
    alert('done');
})
```

The alert is given TWICE when the mouse comes IN any of the children of `#container`.

---

**EDIT 2**

I had to use **`mouseleave`** instead of `mouseout` as the event and this brings us back to the main problem (selecting the default tab):

```
$('#accordion').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#accordion').tabs('select', 1);
})
```

The code stops tabs from changing and completely corrupts the tab bar.

Answer (score 1):

## update

```
$('#accordion').leave(function(){
    // How should I activate a special tab?
   var $accordion = $("#accordion").accordion();
   $accordion.accordion("option","active",1); //go to first tab on mouseleave

});
```

is what you'll need :))

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't help. I can see that even `$('#accordion').mouseout(function(){ alert('done'); });` doesn't work   as expected. It fires twice even when mouse hovers on `#accordion` or its children.

Comment: That's odd... can you provide me with a js fiddle, or just give me all of the code on the page so i can try and find out what might be wrong?

Comment: Unfortunately nor `leave`, neither `mouseleave` doesn't work with the new code: `accordion("option", "active", 1);`